# De Giorgi-Nash-Moser estimattes for non-symmetric a_ij

Tags: regularity-theory-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

Is there any references on De Giorgi-Nash-Moser estimates for the parabolic operator
$$ \partial_t - \partial_j[a_{ij}(t, x)\partial_i] $$
where $a_{ij}$ is **not** symmetric?